# Handling Non Standard Types in RDLC files

Tags: reportviewer, rdlc

I am experiencing a strange issue where a report run locally on one machine works fine, bit on another outputs '#error' when dealing with any fields that are of a type other than the usual string, date or integers. An example is a Field with a type of System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] that is passed through some custom code as below

```
 <Field Name="Equipment">
      <DataField>Equipment</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]</rd:TypeName>
 </Field>

 <Value>=Code.PrintList(Fields!Equipment.Value)</Value>

 <Code>
  Function PrintList(ByVal listToPrint As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)) As String
  Dim sb As new System.Text.StringBuilder
  For Each s As String in listToPrint
  sb.Append(s).AppendLine()
  Next
  return sb.ToString
  End Function
</Code>
```

On one machine this works fine, but on another only #error is output. I am referencing the full namespace of all types so i cant understand why this would work/not work on one machine to another.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: Managed to work this one out myself. The issue was that some machines running Visual Studio 2010 did not have SP1 installed. SP1 apparently fixed some RDLC issues that were causing the problems.